# Access SQL - Join Query after Multiple Unions

Tags: sql, join, union

Apologies if this is a novice question, I'm pretty new to SQL in Access and I'm learning it day by day but this is something that's got away from me. I've got multiple tables that I'm inserting into a Temp Table that overwrites itself each time using Unions.
What I need to do is to connect other tables as Joins, the below is what I am trying to do, but it doesn't work and I was hoping someone who knows this stuff could caste their eyes over it?

I get the error of "Resultant Table not allowed to have more than one Autonumber field".

```
SELECT * INTO [Temp Table]
FROM Calender INNER JOIN ((Product INNER JOIN [Master Lookup] 
                                   ON Product.MASTER = [Master Lookup].Style) 
                                   INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                                               FROM [Table1]
                                               WHERE Week='4314' OR Week='4414'
                                             UNION
                                               SELECT *
                                               FROM [Table2]
                                               WHERE Week='4314' OR Week='4414'
                                             UNION
                                               SELECT *
                                               FROM [Table3]
                                               WHERE Week='4314' OR Week='4414'
                                             UNION
                                              SELECT *
                                              FROM [Table4]
                                              WHERE Week='4314' OR Week='4414'
                                              )  AS a 
                                   ON [Master Lookup].Style = a.Style) 
             ON Calender.Week = a.Week
ORDER BY a.Week;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have more than one `Autonumber` field in your source table, you should convert them into `long`

```
SELECT CLng([auto_id]) AS ID, ... FROM ...
```

Reference: [Resultant tables not allowed to have more than one autonumber field!](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/193493-resultant-tables-not-allowed-have-more-than-one-autonumber-field)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response, if I am specifying the CLng([auto]_id]) then does this mean I have to specify every column in the table I need to extract instead of just writing "Select *"?

Comment: @marcus88 yes, I'm afraid you need to specific all columns in your `select` instead of `select *`

Comment: No worries, I think I've managed to put the fix in that works. I'll put my fixed code in here as an answer for anyone in the future. Thanks for the help!